# PHP Gmail API doesn't fetch emails

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I use the PHP google api with OAuth2.

ALL the process of the token procees
has been successfuly completed.

I use the scopes:

```
$a_scopes = array(
                  Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL,                                                                       
                  Google_Service_Oauth2::PLUS_ME,
                  'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom'                           
                 );

$this->client->setScopes($a_scopes);
```

---

I use the code to retrieve the emails:

```
$plus = new Google_Service_Plus($this->client);
$person = $plus->people->get('me');
$user = $person->getEmails();

echo("<pre>");var_dump($user);die("</pre>");
```

---

The result:

```
array(1) {
   [0]=>
   object(Google_Service_Plus_PersonEmails)#29 (4) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(7) "account"
      ["value"]=>
      string(17) <My Email>
      ["modelData":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
      ["processed":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the atom feed is a defined scope for the API. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) only defines the basic: Modify, ReadOnly and Compose scopes. The Atom Feed only shows you unread messages, and even then only shows [snippets](https://developers.google.com/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed) of the message.

To fix your issue you need to define your scope as one of [those](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes) defined by the Gmail API